# R-Q contains a connected proper subset that is not a single point?

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Does $\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$ contain a connected proper subset that is not a single point?

What is the best way to see the answer to this question?

Comment: @PedroTamaroff I'm not exactly sure how your last sentence helps. It's not true that the connected subsets of a subspace are the intersections of the subspace with the connected subsets of the ambient space.

Comment: @AlexYoucis Maybe I just misunderstood the question completely. =)

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Between any two irrational numbers there is a rational number. So suppose a subset of $\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$ contains two distinct points: can this subset be connected?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose  $\mathbb{J}$  is a connected subset of $\mathbb{R}$ \ $\mathbb{Q}$,which contains atleast two distinct points (say) "a" and "b" .  As  $\mathbb{J}$ is connected and $a,b \in \mathbb{J}$, then  $[a,b] \subset \mathbb{J}$. Which is a contradiction;as:between any two real numbers there is a rational number and $\mathbb{J}$ does not contain any rational number.
Hence $\mathbb{J}$ is a singleton set.

Comment: Please don't use $\mathbb C$ for anything other than the complex numbers. Certain symbols are reserved in order to preserve readability.

Comment: @kahen: I wouldn't go as far as saying that (e.g. in set theory we use $\Bbb Q$ to denote a forcing poset quite often, sometimes $\Bbb{C,R}$ and others are used as well). But in this context I agree that using $\Bbb C$ is a very unfortunate choice of notation.

Comment: @kahen ,Asaf Karagila: hope "J" makes u  happy.